# SqlString in c#

Tags: c#, sql

I just found in some code that it uses `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString`? I haven't seen it used before. Am I always supposed to use this when sending a string to sql server?

e.g.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", (SqlString)FirstName);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's fine - you can just use `string` and the framework/driver will take care of things for you.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think you have to as it will figure it out itself but I always at least say the type just to ensure that it goes through correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are conversions. It should at least be

```
new SqlString(FirstName)
```

there to avoid trouble. SqlString mainly exists to fit in the hierarchy of DbTypes (implementing INullable e.g.)

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to just pass a normal `string`. Nothing wrong with converting to a `SqlString` though; it would be better to call one of the constructors directly though - it can be useful if you want to check locale conversion client side.

I should point out that that method is deprecated and you should be using `AddWithValue` or specifying the field type, and setting the value after.